# Gulp / Unhandled stream error in pipe

Tags: javascript, gulp

I wrote a gulp file that works but...not at any attempts.

Indeed, I get this weird error **1 time / 3**:

```
[12:25:51] Starting 'default'...
[12:25:51] Starting 'clean'...
[12:25:51] Finished 'clean' after 2.96 ms
[12:25:51] Starting 'fonts'...
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: ENOENT, chmod '/Users/UserName/Desktop/frontend/src/assets/fonts/lato/lato-bold-webfont.eot'
```

I even tried setting `chmod -R 777` on the `frontend` folder, but doesn't work either.

**Is this a known issue / bug?** I read all over the web but can't find any good explanation.

Concerned Task is:

```
// copy fonts
gulp.task('fonts', function () {
    return gulp
        .src(['client/assets/fonts/**/*.*', '!client/assets/fonts/**/*.html'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(targetDir, '/assets/fonts')))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
        .on('error', errorHandler);
});
```

Comment: If you delete that one font does the error move to the next one?

Comment: Yes, the error moves to the next one...

Comment: It would't have anthing to do with chmod being a linux command and that being a windows path, would it? Because i think its saying chmod doesnt exist, and if you are on windows...

Comment: I'm on OSX and I also tested on Windows => same issue.

Comment: I've just change the order of runsequence and it works! 
Initially I had runsequence('clean', 'fonts', 'i18n'......).
I switched to : runsequence('clean', 'i18n', 'fonts'......) and it works.
Why? => Mystery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try with the [following gulp task](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-rimraf) (despite being deprecated) to clean directories; instead of `del`:

```
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    rimraf('./' + targetDir, cb);
});
```

And it always works!

Why isn't the `del` command stable? I don't know.